# Can I use same argument names when passing arguments in Python

Tags: python, arguments

Can you please help me guys. I believe I've got pretty easy questions but don't want to stuff up with my assignment. I'm going to have Class in my module, this class will have few functions.

I just want to be sure it works alright and this is a not ugly code practice.
I.e. my first function `test_info` accepts one parameter `test_code` and returns something and the second function `check_class` accepts two parameter, one of them is called `test_code` as well

Can I use same argument name: `test_code`? Is it normal code practice?

```
 def test_info (self, test_code):
   my_test_code = test_code
   #here we'll be using my_test_code to get info from txt file and return other info


 def check_class (self, test_code, other_arg):
   my_test_code = test_code
   #here some code goes
```

Also is it fine to use `my_test_code` in both functions to get argument value or is it better to use different ones like `my_test_code_g` etc.

Many thanks

Comment: The answer to your main question is "yes you can". However, that doesn't mean you always should - it is better to use the same name than add obfuscation like `_g`, but in many cases the called function will take a general argument (e.g. `num`) where the calling function has more information (e.g. `foo_count`) - don't *always* use the same name where doing so would mean losing information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you may.

The two variables `test_code` are defined only in the scope of their respective functions and therefore will not interfere with one another since the other functions lie outside their scope.

Same goes for `my_test_code`

Read online about variable scopes. Here is a [good start](http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/variable-scope.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason to resolve this one way or another. But if the variables don't serve exactly the same purpose in both functions, it's confusing for a human reader if they have the same name.